# Carbon : adding 60seconds interval after the schedule

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

How can insert the addSeconds function in my code? what I want to happen is the match will start 1 minute after the schedule. for example, the schedule is at 3:00, it will start at 3:01. here is the code:

```
public function handle()
{
    $matches = \App\Match::where('status', 'open')->get();
    foreach($matches as $match) {
        if($match->teamA->name == 'TBD' || $match->teamB->name == 'TBD') {
            continue;
        }
        if(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addSeconds(60)->diffForHumans()->diffInSeconds($match->schedule, false) <= 0 && !$match->re_opened) {
            $this->info('[' . \Carbon\Carbon::now() . '] Found match [Match ID: ' . $match->id . '] ' . $match->name . ' - closing...');
            setupOngoingMatch($match);
        }
    }
}
```

but It didn't work. any ideas anyone? TYIA

Answer (score 0):

If the schedule returns a Carbon object, you can simply do the following

```
if($match->schedule->diffInSeconds(\Carbon::now()->addSeconds(60)) => 0 && !$match->re_opened) {
    setupOngoingMatch($match);
}
```

If not just do the following

```php
if(\Carbon::now()->addSeconds(60)->diffInSeconds($match->schedule) => 0 && !$match->re_opened) {
    setupOngoingMatch($match);
}
```

Comment: Sir, I edited my question. that will do but that will just return the same output, what I want to happen is that for example, if the match schedule is at 3:00pm, it will start at 3:01

Comment: Sir, it won't work. it still starts on time without the addsecond function